# Is there an option to run exe files by python like malx.py on TPSC?

Tags: python

i have a trouble programming, my copy of python script executing malware, for AV Tests. I can't find a good line that would run the code that way that my script would work.

```py
import os
import subprocess
import math
import time
import sys, string

samplesDir = r'C:\Users\Tomek\Malware'
samples = 0
for path in os.listdir(samplesDir):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(samplesDir, path)):
        samples += 1
f = 0
s = 0
d = 0
m = 0
p = 0
c = input("Is real-time protection is turned on? ")
mname = ""
if (c == "yes"):
    print("Test succesfully started!")
else:
    exit()

for filename in os.listdir(samplesDir):
        file = (samplesDir, "\\", filename)
        subprocess.Popen(file, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
        time.sleep(0.2)
        p += 1
        print("Progress: ", math.floor(.5 + (p / samples)*100)," % done")
        if (subprocess.CalledProcessError):
            s += 1
            file = samplesDir+"\\"+filename
            print(file, "blocked!")
        else:
            m += 1
            file = samplesDir+"\\"+filename
            print(file, "missed!")
            missed = "\n" + samplesDir + "\\" + filename
            mname = mname + missed
        f += 1
        d = s / f
        print ("Pro-active detection: ",math.floor((100*d+.005)*100)/100, " %")

samplesLeft = 0
for path in os.listdir(samplesDir):
    if os.path.isfile(os.path.join(samplesDir, path)):
        samplesLeft += 1

AVRemovalRate = samplesLeft / samples
print("\n\nTest is completed. ", samples, " samples executed!")
d = s / samples
print ("Final Pro-active detection: ",math.floor((100*d+.005)*100)/100, " %", " Amount of samples missed: ", m)
print ("AntiMalware Quarrantine/Removal Rate: ",100-math.floor((100*AVRemovalRate+.005)*100)/100, " %")
if (mname != ""):
    print("\nSamples Missed:\n", mname)
```

I have no idea how to fix that subprocess line, it works like blocking every file even the .png ones. Does anybody know how i can fix that?

Comment: You need to capture the return value of `Popen` and then wait for the process to complete: `p = subprocess.Popen(...)` and then `p.wait()`. Then errors should be checked on `p`, not on the `subprocess` module. Also, you probably want to either read the pipes you create or redirect stdout/stderr to nul. If you create pipes and you don't read them, the subprocess will block once the pipes get full. Maybe it is a good idea to check the example in the documentation for subprocess.

Comment: thanks for help, but i still have some issues 1st p.wait() makes cmd window wait for the process to complete which is the opposite for what it should do, with pipes i redirected stderr to null and others deleted, so im left with shell, stderr and creationflags, and if i saw correctly it should make a new process group so if an AV detects it, it didn't terminate the script, about the if(p), it didn't really work it behaves the same as earlier. and for what it should do, it should run program wait maybe 0.5s and execute next programs.

Comment: I am not sure why you don't want to wait for completion of the subprocess. If you don't wait for completion at some point then you will leak resources. Also, if you don't wait for completion, then you will never know whether the operating system has actually started running your subprocess. Maybe edit your question to explain what exactly these subprocesses are supposed to do and which results you want to check. For example, do you just want to check whether the subprocess can be started?